# Splitting a String with the pipe symbol as delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

Why is it that in the following, the output is `[]` and not `[1]`?

```
String input="1|2|3";
String[] values= input.split("|");
System.out.println("[" + values[0] + "]");
// Output: []
```

However, if we change the separator, the output is `[1]`.

```
String input="1;2;3";
String[] values= input.split(";");
System.out.println("[" + values[0] + "]");
// Output: [1]
```

Comment: `split(String)` takes a 'regex string' and as such `|` is interpreted as 'regex or' so it doesn't split anything. you should test by escaping `|` and checking that values of `values`

Comment: it does split every character, plus an initial empty string

Answer (score 24):

Try to escape that character:

```
String input="1|2|3";
String[] values= input.split("\\|");
System.out.println("[" + values[0] + "]");
```

Answer (score 15):

Because the `|` has special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape it like this: `\|` and in Java you also have to escape the backslash as well so you end up with `\\|`

The pipe character is a disjunction operator which means that it tells the regular expression engine to choose either pattern on the left and right of it. In your case those where empty strings which match anything.

Answer (score 6):

The `split` method receives a regex as a parameter. The pipe is a reserved character with its own purpose (it means `or`).

You can either escape it (`"\\|"`) or, if you're in Java 1.5+ you can use `Pattern.quote("|")` like this:

```
input.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `\\|` instead of `|` when you split as you need to escape it.

So your code would change to:

```
String input="1|2|3";
String[] values= input.split("\\|");
System.out.println("[" + values[0] + "]");
```

Comment: This will not compile, please check your code. In java you need to double escape, split("\\|").

Comment: @bmorris591 The answer has been modified. Sorry I forgot about it!

Answer (score 3):

you have to escape the character '|' properly

```
String input="1|2|3";
        String[] values= input.split("\\|");
        System.out.println("[" + values[0] + "]");
```

Answer (score -2):

The pipe character is the equivalent to the logical or in a regex. If you really want to use the pipe character as separator, you need to escape it with a `\` as in

`String[] values= input.split("\|");`

Comment: This will not compile, please check your code. In java you need to double escape, `split("\\|")`.